# Cocos2D: SneakyJoystick + Touch Events, problem

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

im having some trouble using SneakyJoystick and ccTouchEnded stuff.

What is my goal, use the joystick to walk around and the touches to interact with the surrounding area.

I have two layers,ControlLayer (z:2) and GamePlayLayer (z:1)
Im Using TiledMap for my ground and map.
The Joystick by it self works fine, it is attached to the ControlLayer. I can walk, colide and stuff.

When i add the Touch events to the GamePlayLayer, the touch works, i can click on something on the "ground" and interact with it. BUT my joystick dosent work then, if i run using the touch the joystick just sit there not responsive.

Here is some of my code, if u guys need more, just ask.

Touch methods in the GameplayLayer

```
-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
   [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self
                                                     priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
}

-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   return YES;
}


-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];      
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
    touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];
    CGPoint tileCoord = [self tileCoordForPosition:touchLocation];
    int tileGid = [meta tileGIDAt:tileCoord];
    if (tileGid) {
        NSDictionary *properties = [tileMap propertiesForGID:tileGid];
        if (properties) {
            NSString *collectable = [properties valueForKey:@"Collectable"];
            if (collectable && [collectable compare:@"True"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                [meta removeTileAt:tileCoord];
                [foreground removeTileAt:tileCoord];
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And how my scene is arranged:

```
@implementation SandBoxScene

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self!=nil) {
        //Control Layer
        controlLayer = [GameControlLayer node];
        [self addChild:controlLayer z:2 tag:2];

        //GamePlayLayer
        GameplayLayer *gameplayLayer = [GameplayLayer node];
        [gameplayLayer connectControlsWithJoystick:[controlLayer leftJoyStick]
                                     andJumpButton:[controlLayer jumpButton]
                                   andAttackButton:[controlLayer attackButton]];
        [self addChild:gameplayLayer z:1 tag:1];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code does not account for multiple touches. Using `-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch..` or `-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch..` will only take one touch... instead you need to use `ccTouchesEnded:..` your method should look something like this:

```
-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    //get your touch from the set of UITouches
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];  

    //the rest below is the same from your method
    CGPoint touchLocation = [myTouch locationInView: [myTouch view]];     

    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
    touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];
    CGPoint tileCoord = [self tileCoordForPosition:touchLocation];
    int tileGid = [meta tileGIDAt:tileCoord];
    if (tileGid) {
        NSDictionary *properties = [tileMap propertiesForGID:tileGid];
        if (properties) {
            NSString *collectable = [properties valueForKey:@"Collectable"];
            if (collectable && [collectable compare:@"True"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                [meta removeTileAt:tileCoord];
                [foreground removeTileAt:tileCoord];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to add `[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];` to your appDelegate. I am not entirely sure that the method above works. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061473/multi-touch-detecting-differentiating-cocos2d-for-iphone) deals with implementing multitouch with cocos2d. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Sorry thats was not the solution, i do want to handle just one touch, the problem was in the priority, i was giving priority 0 to my gameplayLayer, and swalloing every time, so i didnt give chance to the controlayer that had priority 1 to get the touch and act upon my joystick.

The solution that i found was changing the priority from 0 to 2 then, the (controlLayer) joystick would act and pass the touch to the priority 2, that was my gameplayLayer

but thanks anyway :)